# Python - How to check if windows desktop has loaded

Tags: python, windows, desktop, wallpaper

I am wanting to check if my "active desktop" has loaded after startup. This is so I can run my startup routine as if I start it traditionally (drop it in startup folder) then my programs often do not load correctly. An example of this would be when Skype is launched, the tray icon is often missing. Another is when I try to `subst` a drive (using a batch file) it often just doesn't. As a side note, when I log off, then back on, it works fine and everything loads normally, but this is inconvenient.

My active desktop is just a HTML file that loads a looping swf, so there is little lag (compared to gifs) and little CPU usage. Also, FRAPS (running from a service) gives a DirectX 9 warning when the system is booting, before the desktop has loaded.

I have tried several snippets of code to check if explorer.exe has launched, but this is does not help as it continues as normal. I have also tried using `time.sleep` but this is not satisfactory as it is hard to guess the right delay.

-- EDIT --

I have found a roundabout way of fixing this for the meantime. This method is both more and less intensive on CPU. This is because it checks to see if the active window is the desktop, then changes the wallpaper. Otherwise, it 'sleeps' for 3 seconds. For this method to work, I had to extract every layer from my .gif as a .bmp and number them. My full code is as follows:

```
import ctypes
import os.path
import time
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow

## get current directory and add the working path to the end
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '\\wallpaperslides\\'
## find the number of files in this directory
nfiles = len(os.walk(cd).next()[2])

## initialise variables
invalidfiles = 0
fnum = 1

## check to see if every file is numbered and a .bmp
for x in range(nfiles):
    fname = cd + str(x+1) + '.bmp'
    if os.path.isfile(fname) != True:
        ## makes sure all of the files are there, otherwise...
        print fname + ' doesn\'t exist'
        invalidfiles = 1

## ...tell the user to fix
if invalidfiles == 1:
    print 'All files should be numbered and in bitmap format'
    print ''
    raw_input('Press enter to exit\n')
    raise SystemExit

elif invalidfiles == 0:
    ## Main loop
    while True:
        ## Find active window, if it is the desktop...
        if GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()) == '' or GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()) == 'Program Manager':
            ## Set wallpaper
            ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20,0,cd + str(fnum) + '.bmp',0)
            ## increase index
            fnum += 1
            ## reset index if it exceeds the number of files in the folder
            if fnum > nfiles:
                fnum = 1
            ## Delay animation
            time.sleep(0.05)
        ## ...otherwise, do nothing.
        else:
            time.sleep(3)
```